# Mathematica StackedList Plot error : An option must be a rule or a list of rules

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the given equation as a StackedListPlot. It works normally when I use the Plot function but does not work when I use the StackedList Plot.

```
    params = {c -> 1, e -> .1, u -> .5, m -> 0.001, q -> .2};
    fig1a = StackedListPlot[{1/(
         2 c d (c + d - q)) (c^2 d + c d^2 + 2 c^2 e + c d e - d^2 e + 
           c^2 m + c d m - 2 c d q - c e q + d e q - c m q + d m q + 
           c^2 u + c d u - 
           c Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - 
                q) + (d (e + 2 m) - (e + m) q + c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2] -
            d Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - 
                q) + (d (e + 2 m) - (e + m) q + 
               c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2]) /. params, (
        c d - 2 c e - d e - c m - 2 d m + e q + m q - c u + 
         Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - q) + (d (e + 2 m) - (e + m) q +
             c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2])/(2 d (c + d - q)) /. params}, {d, 
       0, 2} , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

I am getting the error

An option must be a rule or a set of rules

Comment: It would have been clearer if you quoted the whole error: "options expected (instead of `{d,0,2}`)...". This is a `ListPlot`: you should provide it numerical values only. You can't specify a range for the independent variable. Use `Plot` instead of `StackedListPlot` and you'll get your result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[func]
func[d_] := {1/(2 c d (c + d - q)) (c^2 d + c d^2 + 2 c^2 e + c d e - 
  d^2 e + c^2 m + c d m - 2 c d q - c e q + d e q - c m q + 
  d m q + c^2 u + c d u - c Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - q) + 
  (d (e + 2 m) - (e + m) q + c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2] - 
  d Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - q) + (d (e + 2 m) - 
  (e + m) q + c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2]), 
 (c d - 2 c e - d e - c m - 2 d m + e q + 
  m q - c u + Sqrt[-4 d m (-c + e + m) (c + d - q) + 
  (d (e + 2 m) - (e + m) q + c (-d + 2 e + m + u))^2])/(2 d (c + d - q))} /.
 params;
```

You can use `Plot` (as suggested by MarcoB in comments) processing with [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html)  the two components of `func[d]`:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Accumulate @ func[d], {d, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> {1}}]
```

[image]

If you have to use `StackedListPlot`, use `func[d]` to generate a data set that `StackedListPlot` will accept:

```
slpdata = Transpose@Table[func[d], {d, 10^-4, 2, .05}];

StackedListPlot[slpdata, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, DataRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]